# Android: Programmatically fire a touch event

Tags: android, events, android-webview

Is there any way to do this? When a WebView page loads I need to fire a simple touch event.

**EDIT**

*performClick()*

and

*MotionEvent.obtain(...)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a onClickListener set on a `View` (and a WebView extends View, so that will work) you can call the [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29) method.

Comment: ah thanks. I'm trying to call a touch event after a page loads, but it's not working.

Comment: What exactly does this touch event do? Wouldn't it be possible to just run a specific method instead?

Comment: It's ok, I figured out a workaround. I was working with jQuery SVG and hardware acceleration. When I clicked on an image a page wouldn't load directly, rather it would show a blank white page, and after a touch event, it would show the page.